# need help spliting a list into 2 different list

Tags: ruby

This is my code it creates a list of 20 items and I want to split it into 2 lists of 10 and only display one list at a time. How can I make this happen in ruby?

```
def list_dogs
counter = 0
if counter <= 10
  Dogs::DogsPopularity.all.each do |dog|

    puts "#{counter +=1}. #{dog.name}"
    #binding.pry
  end

elsif counter > 10 && counter <= 20
  Dogs::DogsPopularity.all.each do |dog|
    puts "#{counter +=1}. #{dog.name}"
  #  binding.pry
  end
end
#binding.pry
end
```

This is what it prints out.....

1. Labrador Retriever
2. Golden Retriever
3. Bulldog
4. Beagle
5. French Bulldog
6. Poodle
7. Yorkshire Terrier
8. Boxer
9. Dachshund
10. Australian Shepherd
11. Pembroke Welsh Corgi
12. Cavalier King Charles Spaniel
13. Shih Tzu
14. Boston Terrier
15. Havanese
16. Brittany
17. American Cocker Spaniel
18. Chihuahua
19. Pug
20. Maltese

Comment: do you know basic ruby at all?

Comment: I was going to suggest `Dogs::DogsPopularity.all.in_groups_of 10`, but the basic Ruby needs to be addressed first

Answer (score 0):

We have to assume that your class/module returns 20 dogs, and if so:

```
def list_dogs
  Dogs::DogsPopularity.all.each_slice(10).each do |dog_arr|
    dog_arr.each_with_index do |dog, i|
      puts "#{i+1}. #{dog.name}"
    end
  end
end
```

To see that this works on a basic array see:

```
[*1..100].each_slice(10).each_with_index{|arr, i| puts "#{i+1}: #{arr}"}
```